# multi request in wordpress ajax plugin at the same time

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

why wordpress not allow to run multi request at the same time in admin-ajax.php ? 
when I send these two action **iwannawait** and **idontwannawait** to "admin-ajax.php" at the same time , previous request must be complete (in this , code wait for 60s) and next request will start ..
I tried multi url query for passing browser waiting requests (**admin-ajax.php?req1** .. **admin-ajax.php?req2** but is still not work

```
add_action('wp_ajax_iwannawait', 'iwannawait');
add_action('wp_ajax_idontwannawait', 'idontwannawait');

function iwannawait()
{
sleep(60); 
echo "60!";
die();      
}

function idontwannawait()
{
echo "0!";
die();      
}
```

Comment: The session is probably locked by php.

Comment: No I tried this outside wordpress plugin and that works !

Comment: and thats why wordpress sucks ...